# How can I launch js-file from html-page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I launch server, which go to the web page index.html. There is the button on the webpage. I want to Click on this button and launch gotest.js, which starts up tests ( such as loginTest.js ). How can I do this?

server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var app = express();
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "index.html");
});
app.listen(1234);
console.log("Server has started!");
```

index.html:

```
<button>Launch Selenium Autotest</button> // or any another HTML-element
```

gotest.js:

```
const { loginTest } = require("loginTest");
const autotest = async () => {
  await loginTest();
};
try {
  autotest();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

loginTest.js:

```
const { By, Key, until } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");

module.exports = {
  loginTest: async () => {

      let driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      try {
        await driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
        console.log("DONE");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      } finally {
        await driver.quit();
      }
   }
 };
```

Comment: you want to run test on the server?

Comment: @RahulPadalkar , I want to run test clicking on the <button> on the html page

Answer (score 0):

Put id and the js file to run on click in button

```
<button onclick="gotest.js" id="btnmodal" data-modal="btnmodal">Launch yourFirstJS file</button>
```

Put this script in header , should Auto click the above button on page load

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#btnmodal').click();
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps